# Concurrent ad requests on AdMob

Tags: android, admob

If user goes from one activity with adView to another activity with adView and continue to do this, there will be many ad requests... Isn't this a problem for Admob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to a new activity, the AdView from the first activity should be destroyed, and that ad just won't show. So there isn't a technical limitation here. However, by putting ads on screens where users spend very little of their time, you may see low click through rates and increased network usage, which is not great for you or your users.

Comment: Thank you."Another activity" also means an orientation change, as it will recreate the current activity, it will also increase request count. Do you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: By default, orientation change does recreate the activity. If you choose to, you can add the `orientation` config change to your activity to not have it redraw, and you can handle the change yourself. In that case, the AdView won't get destroyed either. However, I think rotations don't occur as often as activity switching within apps. Most apps are suited for a single orientation, and users tend to stay in that orientation.